# How to resolve error: java: symbol lookup error

Tags: java, symbols, lookup, undefined-symbol

I am trying to run a software in x86_64 GNU/Linux, developed by the FCC called SATFC. The software calls up a sat-solver named satenstein and when it does i get the following error message:

java: symbol lookup error: /tmp/libjnasatenstein_15758433517075266088.so: undefined symbol: AddToList1

**Let me note that i have already set up satenstein in my system as the manual of the software indicated.

Thanks for your help!

***EDIT

I run : nm -D libjnasatenstein_15758433517075266088.so
to examine the library and it shows the following about the symbol:

------------  U AddToList1

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly too late, but I was working with the same SATFC library and facing the same issue. After a lot of digging I was able to resolve it. I think there's an issue with the SATenstein build code, which I had to tweak to get it to work. Navigate to the SATenstein source directory (if you're using the source inside the SATFC project, it should be at `satfc/src/dist/satenstein/ubcsat_stein`). Inside, edit the CMakeLists.txt file: add the flag `-std=gnu89` to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS. Recompile the SATenstein project. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

most likely to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable not being set to include the  satenstein-libs  append the same to the  LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:<path_to_satenstein_lib>
```

Comment: I was not able to fix it even though i get the felling that you are right. Just to make sure as the <path_to_satenstein_lib> i am using /tmp as i get in the error, am i right?